# (Swift/FireStore)How to put URL to StringArray

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 func fetchData(){

        let saveDocument = Firestore.firestore()

       guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else{
                      return
                  }

            let uploadDocument = saveDocument.collection("upLoad").document(user.uid) .collection("Posts")

    uploadDocument.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in


            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    if let foodValue =

        document.data()["FoodImage"] as? String{

     self.foodImageArray.append(foodValue)
            }
print(self.foodImageArray)
                }
```

↑ This time , I can print **foodImageArray**

```
  var foodImageArray: [String] = []
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
 print(foodImageArray)
    }
```

↑However ,this time when i try to print out the item, 
it printed out like **[]**(null)

I want to put my Items in **foodImageArray**
and show them in cell

How can I put my items taken by cloudFirestore to foodImageArray?

Comment: Also, format your code, Xcode will do it for you just follow these commands -> `CMD` + `a` -> `CONTROL` + `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print out once the fetch is completed which takes time and is run as a background task. To get the result you received when you print, modify `fetchData` to look like this:

```swift
func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let saveDocument = Firestore.firestore()

    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else{
        return
    }

    let uploadDocument = saveDocument.collection("upLoad").document(user.uid).collection("Posts")

    uploadDocument.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                if let foodValue = document.data()["FoodImage"] as? String{
                    self.foodImageArray.append(foodValue)
                }
            }
        }
        completion?()
    }
}
```

And call `fetchData` like this:

```swift
var foodImageArray: [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData {
        print(self.foodImageArray)
    }
}
```

Note: This is only an example a much better approach is to pass the array as a parameter in the completion block.